# Get Facebook friends list on login

Tags: facebook, api

I need to get all the friends list of the logged in user.
  But I'm stuck with the how to fetch results.

```
  $user = $facebook->getUser();
  $user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friendslist', array('fields'=>'id,name'));
  print_r($user_friends);
```

I'm getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Unknown path components: /friendslist thrown base_facebook.php on line 1254
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are correctly logged in?

Comment: It should be `/me/friends`. But if you're using a v2.0 app, this will only give you the friends who also use the app

Comment: i think it´s /me/friendlists, not /me/friendlist - also, what tobi said.

Comment: yup, i was right: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friendlists

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friendlists

It is `/me/friendlists`, not `/me/friendlist`. Although this will not get you the friends of the user, but only the friendlists he created to sort his friends.

To get the friends you would have to use `/me/friends`, although you will only get the friends who are using your App too. See the changelog for more information about the changes from April 2014: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog